# Getting Two Add to cart in Bundle Products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

you can see in image there are two buttons, of which i want to delete one button[image]When I configure a bundle product i'm getting two add to cart buttons, I edited "addtocart.phtml" and "view.phtml".
but still I'm not able to remove one addtocart button..!!

Comment: could you explain more details

Comment: I had configured Bundle Products, so the problem is that I'm getting Two add to cart Buttons in "Product View Page".It's only one button when any Single Product is Viewed, but whenever I open Bundle Product it's showing two add to cart button...!! i want to keep only one button..!!!

Comment: @Devs you can see in the above pic..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you select wrong file. I'll guide you correct way. follow the below steps and solve your problem.

1. Log into the magento back-end admin
2. List item Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED Switch to the
   store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
4. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a
   new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
   hints.

> Remember to clear your cache.

- get correct path for your cart button and remove them from file.

If you still getting problem let me know by comment of this answer.